# Typescript: remove null from union

Tags: typescript

Given a type:

```
type Foo = string | null
```

Is there a way I can create a new type, that excludes `null`:

```js
function returnSomething(input: Foo): RemoveFromUnion<Foo, null> {

  if (input === null) throw new Error('No.');
  return input;

}
```

Or more generically:

```js
function returnSomething<T>(input: T): RemoveFromUnion<T, null> {

  if (input === null) throw new Error('No.');
  return input;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) utility type.

```
type T1 = string | number | unknown[] | null;
type T2 = Exclude<T1, number | null>; // type T2 = string | unknown[]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple to do

```
type newType = Exclude<T, null>
```

This will filter null from T type

Answer (score 0):

Btw, there is built in util type: `NonNullable`. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype)

```js
type A = number | null
type B = string | undefined

type Result = NonNullable<A> // number
type Result2 = NonNullable<B> // string
```

It has next type signature:

```js
// old TS version
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T

// new TS version
type NonNullable<T> = T & {}
```

Comment: This excludes `undefined`, and `undefined !== null`

Comment: Thanks for information. I know, since I provided type signature

Comment: I appreciate it! Still useful information